# Novel about revolution on a lost colony

Tags: story-identification, novel

This novel was written in the 1980s (I think.)

It took place on a lost or abandoned colony planet. There was an island where a man was hiding with debt notes from people who owed friends.  He was protecting those debts from being paid off with fiat money. The island came with slow agonizing death from killer plants.

One character's name was I think "Shulamit(h) Well(e)s", she was the daughter of the man mentioned above. There was one scene in an underground tunnel with a river flowing through it. Two brothers were on the side of the revolution. There were shady characters’ attempts to arrest opposition legislatures.

It wasn't any of the *War World* novels.

There was an "Operation Ladybug" meant to intimidate good guy members of the "congress" - "Ladybug, Ladybug, fly away home.  Your house is on fire and your children will burn."

My impression of the paperback is that it was generally green.

Comment: Are there any sci-fi or fantasy elements in this story? With a first glance, it seems not. If this is the case then I am afraid your question might be off topic.

Comment: Fiat money has killer plants? Sounds sci-fi to me!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I think I would say "keep the change"

Comment: Maybe one of the chronologically early stories in the War World series by John Carr? Miners and pot farmers form a loose union to resist corporate control of the colony world.

Comment: When you say, "lost or abandoned colony" are you referring to a colony on another planet, or somewhere on Earth?  What level of technology/civilization (eg. was it a planet that was colonized but not in contact with the rest of humanity, and reverted to an agricultural society, a feudal system, etc.?  Or still a modern technological society?

Comment: @basya A technological society that had lost contact with "Earth/Humanity".  They were still technological but had lost some technology.

Comment: The man who was hiding on the island had "debt notes" from his friends, i.e., they owed him money. So why was he hiding? And what's with the friends not wanting to be paid off in fiat money? Paid off by whom for what? Was the colony's hard currency backed by precious metals?

Comment: the debt notes were from others who owed money to his friends.  He was hiding on the island to protect those notes from being redeemed with fiat currency

Answer (score 6):

Could it be part of the Jerry Pournelle "War World" series? War World: Blood Feuds

[The chronology site](http://www.chronology.org/noframes/pournelle/timeline.html) seems to suggest there is a Shulamit character on the Haven Colony planet.

> Late 2992**
>   WAR WORLD: BLOOD FEUDS, chapters 13-16 (pp. 315-401 only). 
>   Haven:    Temujin captured. Shulamit and Karl meet Sigrid. The Seven rally the clans of the Northern Steppes.
>
> WAR WORLD: BLOOD VENGEANCE, Prologue. 
>   Haven:    Shulamit learns the truth about Sigrid.
>
> 2996/97**
>   "Shame and Honor" (WWIII 270-356). 
>   Haven:    Shulamit bat Miriam fan Gimbutas allies with a Sauron. Karl bar Yigal fan Reenan defends the Pale from an invasion*

Comment: Novels in the 80s seemed to include every Tom, Dick, and Shulamit, though.